# Permissions issue with git

Tags: permissions, git

I have a development machine that use runs on CentOs.

Whenever i pull from git using `git pull` i get "permission denied" issue/error.

Git apparently doesn't have the permission to overwrite the files needed when i do a pull. Thus after every time i have to `sudo git pull` to get it to work.

I would rather not do a `sudo git pull` because i'd like everyone to be able to pull from our development server.

How do i configure git to have the proper permissions to just be able to pull without `sudo`ing?  Is this because I may have not configured git properly? If so how do i configure git to allow the correct permissions?

Not sure if this helps but a `which git` reveals this:

`/usr/bin/git`

**Example error**

i execute: `git commit -m "my fun message"`
i get:

> error: Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/stage: Permission denied
>   fatal: cannot update HEAD ref

Comment: “Permission denied” from what? Is the repository local or remote? What are the permissions on the repository?

Comment: Good point. I've updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git itself doesn't have any permissions. It relies entirely on the operating system level permissions.

If you're the only person using that git repo, then do this:

```
cd dir_of_repo
sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME} $(pwd)
sudo chmod -R u+rwX $(pwd)
```

If you're sharing this with other people, then you probably need to read [Understanding UNIX permissions and chmod](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml).

Comment: What do those commands do?

Comment: You should read that link that I already posted. Those commands make you the owner and give you full permission over the repo directory.