# Run git pull from a shell start-up script

Tags: shell, permissions, python, git

I have Raspberry Pi that loads a shell script on start up.

This script runs a python script, `boot_camera.py`, which is found in a repository.

I Have a server which sends the Raspberry Pi a command to issue a `git pull` command. The git pull command fails when the `boot_camera.py` is loaded on start-up.

However when I load the 'boot_camera.py' script manually after connecting with ssh the `git pull` command is executed successfully.

At first I thought the problem was with having to use 'sudo' permissions to run the command, so I used this solution which fixed the problem:

[>>>Solution to not using sudo<<<](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/permissions-issue-with-git)

But when the script is booted on start-up the `pull` command still fails.

Update:
This is the script that sets up the boot script:

```
sudo cp bootCameraModule.sh /etc/init.d/
sudo update-rc.d bootCameraModule.sh defaults
```

And this is the script itself:

```
case "$1" in
start)
    echo "Starting camera"
    . /home/pi/.virtualenvs/env/bin/activate
    # run application
    cd /home/pi/rpi-repo/rpi/
    python boot_camera.py &
 ;;
stop)
    echo "Stopping camera"
    # kill application
    sudo killall camera
;;
*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/bootCameraModule {start|stop}"
    exit 1
;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: You need to show us the scripts that you're running. Also your text is hard to read. Use shorter sentences and start sentences with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my message and added the relevant Shell scripts.

Comment: Can you show us `boot_camera.py`?

Comment: Messing around with code that is critical for the function of your machine by grabbing a *latest development version* automatically and installing that is less than wise...

Comment: Might be an old question but I will guess the issue is related to a non full path to an executable in `boot_camera.py`. For example `git` is used instead of `/path/to/git`. This is due to the start environment being different the user environment.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the script itself, one strong possibility I'd suggest investigating is that the networking isn't fully level by the time your script executes. The reason it manually succeeds is that you've executed it after the networking is fully up.

I have a git repo my own pi camera application is dependent on for shoveling pictures & videos it captures to the cloud. My script just keep looping the `git clone` until it either succeeds or at least makes me aware its failed:

```
until git clone https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader.git
do
    echo
    echo "Download of Dropbox-Uploader repo failed. Retrying"
    echo "CTRL +C to exit if failing endlessly"
    echo
done
```